# Airflow: ERROR - object of type 'int' has no len()

Tags: airflow

Requirement: To extra data from snowflake and insert into oracle table

Issue: ERROR - object of type 'int' has no len()

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 978, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/plugins/bi_plugin.py", line 5437, in execute
    orcl.bulk_insert_rows(table=self.oracle_table, rows=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/hooks/oracle_hook.py", line 210, in bulk_insert_rows
    values=', '.join(':%s' % i for i in range(1, len(values_base) + 1)),
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Code:

```
 def __init__(self,snowflake_conn_id, oracle_conn_id, sql,oracle_table,target_fields, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.snowflake_conn_id = snowflake_conn_id
    self.oracle_conn_id = oracle_conn_id
    self.sql = sql
    self.oracle_table=oracle_table
    self.target_fields=target_fields

def get_records(self, hook, sql):
    with closing(hook.get_conn()) as conn:
        with closing(conn.cursor()) as cur:
            cur.execute(sql)
            while True:
                results = cur.fetchmany(size=10000)
                if not results:
                    break
                for result in results:
                    yield result

def execute(self, context):
    snflk_hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id=self.snowflake_conn_id)
    orcl = OracleHook(oracle_conn_id=self.oracle_conn_id)
    logging.info("Inserting rows into Oracle")
    for result in self.get_records(snflk_hook, self.sql):
        orcl.bulk_insert_rows(table=self.oracle_table, rows=[result], target_fields = self.target_fields)
```

> EDIT - Solution worked with Mike suggestion

But it's very slow, How can I get the insert in the bulk of 10000 rows or faster means. Does loading from file to insert into the Table faster?
It is inserting as each row

```
[2020-09-28 12:54:25,346] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-09-28 12:54:25,346] {oracle_hook.py:229} INFO - [table_name] inserted 1 rows
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is `OracleHook.bulk_insert_rows(rows=result)` just isn't passing the right type to the rows argument. The Error clearly states there's no len() on whatever value is passed to `len(values_base)` in the `oracle_hook.py` code.

This suggests that it expects a `Collection` type. You may want to inspect what type `result` is at the time you make this call. And you may find you want to coerce it to a collection such as `orcl.bulk_insert_rows(table=self.oracle_table, rows=[result])`....

My guess is from `bulk_insert_rows()` you  are expecting to load a List of Lists. And at the  moment you are only passing a List

Comment: Thanks it worked but its very slow, How can I get the insert in the bulk of 10000 rows or faster means. Does loading from file to insert into the Table faster? It is inserting as each row 
`[2020-09-28 12:54:25,346] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-09-28 12:54:25,346] {oracle_hook.py:229} INFO - [table_name] inserted 1 rows
`

Comment: Can you please help me the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64105653/airflow-load-large-data-from-s3-to-oracle-table-ora-01008-not-all-variables

Comment: The thing to do would to not have an iterator at all. So rather than use a for loop and yield in  your function... return all the rows. And then pass all the rows into the bulk_insert_rows() all at once

Comment: You meant pass directly `self.get_records(snflk_hook, self.sql)` to the rows in the function `bulk_insert_rows`

Comment: yes, something like that. the original function returns a multiple rows and the bulk insert inserts multiple rows. that's how I'd read those two functions